# How will be a Component Diagram for Salesforce Project, if we have like this in .Net project

Tags: force.com, documentation

[image]

Hi everyone, I have to draw a Component Diagram for Salesforce App I have developed to add in my Project Report Documentation.
I have attached here a example image of Component Diagram for .Net projects, so what type of pages and extensions we do use in Salesforce ! Any Suggestions or Idea,
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2):

When code is extracted from a Salesforce org using the Metadata API, files for named components are created e.g. .cls files for Apex classes and .page files for Visualforce pages. So if you want to use a file name extension in some documentation, you should probably use those. They are referenced in e.g. this document [Metadata API Developer’s Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf).